# How to Consume JSON Array in Apex REST API Class : Stuck with deserialization Error

Tags: json, apexrest

I am giving this below JSON array to a REST API-POST Method : So I can insert Account and Contact, but keep getting an error on JSON deserialization of apex parameter. I don't know how shall i go about it.. Any suggestion would be helpful?

also if i can get some link of reference material to better understand how APex Class consumes JSON data. Thanks!!

```
{
    "rTest": [{
        "sName": "REST Account",
        "sRating": "Hot",
        "sContact": "Rest Contact"
    }, {
        "sName": "REST Account",
        "sRating": "Hot",
        "sContact": "Rest Contact"
    }]
}
```

Comment: can you post you apex code ( http post method)

Comment: @rao : I am new to this, so not doing much in APex, just written code to see the data :                                 
    global static string  PutAccConMultipl(String rTest)
    {
                     system.debug(rTest); // to see the data that it gets from the request
       system.debug(JSON.deserializeUntyped(rTest)); // to see the deserialized data  passed in here
        return 'done';
     
    }

Comment: I even tried with this :                                                      @HttpPost
    global static String createMerchandise(String merch)
    {
     
     List<Account> tt =   (List<Account>)System.JSON.deserialize(merch, List<@HttpPost
    global static String createMerchandise(String merch)
    {
     
     List<Merchandise__c> tt =   (List<Merchandise__c>)System.JSON.deserialize(rTest, List<Merchandise__c>.class);
        system.debug(tt);
   return 'done'
}>.class);
        system.debug(tt);
   return 'done'
}

Comment: What exactly is the deserialization error?

Comment: https://json2apex.herokuapp.com is your friend. Automatically makes the correct classes given a certain JSON.

Comment: That's pretty cool - didn't know about json2apex

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `{` starts an object and the `[` starts an array. It is convenient to deserialise into inner classes (because the class field names must match the JSON names) and then transfer from those into the SObjects:

```
public class Item {
    public String sName;
    public String sRating;
    public String sContact;
}

@HttpPost
global static String createMerchandise(Item[] rTest) {
    Account[] accounts = new Account[] {};
    for (Item i : rTest) {
        accounts.add(new Account(Name = i.sName, ??? = i.sRating));
    }
    // Other logic relating to Contact?
}
```

The parameters of the method must match the root JSON object field names and types.

The platform does the deserialisation from JSON to Apex objects automatically if you use the above pattern.

**update: fixed a typo in Account creation code**

Comment: But got a query, I could see unlike single record processing, when we process JSON array, we have declared a class Item with all the variables we are using in JSON.. I dint get, Why there is a need to do this Class item declaration only for multiple records and not in single record processing...Pl explain?

Comment: @user10727 For a single record the method signature could be `createMerchandise(String sName, String sRating, String sContact)` but without the extra class all you could do would be `createMerchandise(String[] sName, String[] sRating, String[] sContact)` which is very different JSON. The class provides a group of fields and then you can have an array of those groups of felds.

Answer (score 0):

How to write test class for global static String createMerchandise(Item[] rTest) ? I have this type of error :
Method does not exist or incorrect signature: Class.createMerchandise(List

Comment: Post your code also

Comment: Hi Chris, welcome to SFSE. Please take a moment to visit the [help] and read [ask] and [answer]. If you have a question to ask, please post a question instead of an answer. You can link to this question if it helps provide context.